# Heroku deployment with active_admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, heroku, activeadmin

I write simple statistic app with active_admin interface and i wan't to host it on heroku. When i type git push heroku master i have the following error:

```
 Fetching git://github.com/gregbell/active_admin.git
       fatal: Could not parse object 'ac4918ef99cf0272eb5f744b7e3f3fc7cde5811f'.
       Git error: command `git reset --hard ac4918ef99cf0272eb5f744b7e3f3fc7cde5811f`
       in directory
       /tmp/build_8776c788-ed11-4ae5-b374-8618b8523219/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bundler/gems/active_admin-ac4918ef99cf
       has failed.
       If this error persists you could try removing the cache directory
       '/tmp/build_8776c788-ed11-4ae5-b374-8618b8523219/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/cache/bundler/git/active_admin-d67faab65e9b74efbc8efb4a777a851e9f78b2ca'
       Bundler Output: Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/........
       Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
       Fetching git://github.com/gregbell/active_admin.git
       fatal: Could not parse object 'ac4918ef99cf0272eb5f744b7e3f3fc7cde5811f'.
       Git error: command `git reset --hard ac4918ef99cf0272eb5f744b7e3f3fc7cde5811f`
       in directory
       /tmp/build_8776c788-ed11-4ae5-b374-8618b8523219/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bundler/gems/active_admin-ac4918ef99cf
       has failed.
       If this error persists you could try removing the cache directory
       '/tmp/build_8776c788-ed11-4ae5-b374-8618b8523219/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/cache/bundler/git/active_admin-d67faab65e9b74efbc8efb4a777a851e9f78b2ca'
 !
 !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
 !

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby/Rails app

To git@heroku.com:intense-forest-6444.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:intense-forest-6444.git'
```

this is my gemfile.lock:

```
GIT
  remote: git://github.com/bmabey/database_cleaner.git
  revision: df55cf7b746e792dba1d11eea0d6e31e3abc7e8c
  specs:
    database_cleaner (1.1.1)

GIT
  remote: git://github.com/gregbell/active_admin.git
  revision: ac4918ef99cf0272eb5f744b7e3f3fc7cde5811f
  branch: rails4
  specs:
    activeadmin (0.6.0)
      arbre (>= 1.0.1)
      bourbon (>= 1.0.0)
      coffee-rails (>= 3.2.0)
      devise (>= 3.0.2)
      formtastic (>= 2.3.0.rc2)
      inherited_resources (>= 1.4.1)
      jquery-rails (>= 3.0.0)
      jquery-ui-rails (>= 4.0.0)
      kaminari (>= 0.13.0)
      rails (>= 3.2.0)
      ransack (>= 1.0.0)
      sass-rails (>= 3.2.0)

GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    actionmailer (4.0.0)
      actionpack (= 4.0.0)
      mail (~> 2.5.3)
    actionpack (4.0.0)
      activesupport (= 4.0.0)
      builder (~> 3.1.0)
      erubis (~> 2.7.0)
      rack (~> 1.5.2)
      rack-test (~> 0.6.2)
    activemodel (4.0.0)
      activesupport (= 4.0.0)
      builder (~> 3.1.0)
    activerecord (4.0.0)
      activemodel (= 4.0.0)
      activerecord-deprecated_finders (~> 1.0.2)
      activesupport (= 4.0.0)
      arel (~> 4.0.0)
    activerecord-deprecated_finders (1.0.3)
    activesupport (4.0.0)
      i18n (~> 0.6, >= 0.6.4)
      minitest (~> 4.2)
      multi_json (~> 1.3)
      thread_safe (~> 0.1)
      tzinfo (~> 0.3.37)
    addressable (2.3.5)
    arbre (1.0.1)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
    arel (4.0.0)
    atomic (1.1.14)
    bcrypt-ruby (3.1.2)
    bootstrap-sass (2.3.2.2)
      sass (~> 3.2)
    bourbon (3.1.8)
      sass (>= 3.2.0)
      thor
    builder (3.1.4)
    capybara (2.1.0)
      mime-types (>= 1.16)
      nokogiri (>= 1.3.3)
      rack (>= 1.0.0)
      rack-test (>= 0.5.4)
      xpath (~> 2.0)
    childprocess (0.3.9)
      ffi (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.11)
    climate_control (0.0.3)
      activesupport (>= 3.0)
    cocaine (0.5.1)
      climate_control (>= 0.0.3, < 1.0)
    coffee-rails (4.0.0)
      coffee-script (>= 2.2.0)
      railties (>= 4.0.0.beta, < 5.0)
    coffee-script (2.2.0)
      coffee-script-source
      execjs
    coffee-script-source (1.6.3)
    countries (0.9.2)
      currencies (>= 0.4.0)
    currencies (0.4.2)
    devise (3.1.0)
      bcrypt-ruby (~> 3.0)
      orm_adapter (~> 0.1)
      railties (>= 3.2.6, < 5)
      thread_safe (~> 0.1)
      warden (~> 1.2.3)
    diff-lcs (1.2.4)
    erubis (2.7.0)
    execjs (2.0.1)
    factory_girl (4.2.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
    factory_girl_rails (4.2.1)
      factory_girl (~> 4.2.0)
      railties (>= 3.0.0)
    ffi (1.9.0)
    formtastic (2.3.0.rc2)
      actionpack (>= 3.0)
    growl (1.0.3)
    haml (4.0.3)
      tilt
    haml-rails (0.4)
      actionpack (>= 3.1, < 4.1)
      activesupport (>= 3.1, < 4.1)
      haml (>= 3.1, < 4.1)
      railties (>= 3.1, < 4.1)
    has_scope (0.6.0.rc)
      actionpack (>= 3.2, < 5)
      activesupport (>= 3.2, < 5)
    hike (1.2.3)
    i18n (0.6.5)
    inherited_resources (1.4.1)
      has_scope (~> 0.6.0.rc)
      responders (~> 1.0.0.rc)
    jbuilder (1.5.1)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
      multi_json (>= 1.2.0)
    jquery-rails (3.0.4)
      railties (>= 3.0, < 5.0)
      thor (>= 0.14, < 2.0)
    jquery-ui-rails (4.0.5)
      railties (>= 3.1.0)
    json (1.8.0)
    kaminari (0.14.1)
      actionpack (>= 3.0.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
    launchy (2.3.0)
      addressable (~> 2.3)
    mail (2.5.4)
      mime-types (~> 1.16)
      treetop (~> 1.4.8)
    mime-types (1.25)
    mini_portile (0.5.1)
    minitest (4.7.5)
    multi_json (1.8.0)
    nokogiri (1.6.0)
      mini_portile (~> 0.5.0)
    orm_adapter (0.4.0)
    paperclip (3.5.1)
      activemodel (>= 3.0.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
      cocaine (~> 0.5.0)
      mime-types
    pg (0.17.0)
    pg_search (0.7.0)
      activerecord (>= 3.1)
      activesupport (>= 3.1)
      arel
    phony (1.9.0)
    phony_rails (0.4.2)
      activesupport (>= 3.0)
      countries (>= 0.8.2)
      phony (>= 1.7.7)
    polyamorous (0.6.4)
      activerecord (>= 3.0)
    polyglot (0.3.3)
    rack (1.5.2)
    rack-test (0.6.2)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    rails (4.0.0)
      actionmailer (= 4.0.0)
      actionpack (= 4.0.0)
      activerecord (= 4.0.0)
      activesupport (= 4.0.0)
      bundler (>= 1.3.0, < 2.0)
      railties (= 4.0.0)
      sprockets-rails (~> 2.0.0)
    rails_12factor (0.0.2)
      rails_serve_static_assets
      rails_stdout_logging
    rails_serve_static_assets (0.0.1)
    rails_stdout_logging (0.0.2)
    railties (4.0.0)
      actionpack (= 4.0.0)
      activesupport (= 4.0.0)
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      thor (>= 0.18.1, < 2.0)
    rake (10.1.0)
    ransack (1.0.0)
      actionpack (>= 3.0)
      activerecord (>= 3.0)
      polyamorous (~> 0.6.0)
    rb-fsevent (0.9.3)
    rdoc (3.12.2)
      json (~> 1.4)
    responders (1.0.0)
      railties (>= 3.2, < 5)
    rspec-core (2.14.5)
    rspec-expectations (2.14.3)
      diff-lcs (>= 1.1.3, < 2.0)
    rspec-mocks (2.14.3)
    rspec-rails (2.14.0)
      actionpack (>= 3.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0)
      railties (>= 3.0)
      rspec-core (~> 2.14.0)
      rspec-expectations (~> 2.14.0)
      rspec-mocks (~> 2.14.0)
    rubyzip (0.9.9)
    sass (3.2.10)
    sass-rails (4.0.0)
      railties (>= 4.0.0.beta, < 5.0)
      sass (>= 3.1.10)
      sprockets-rails (~> 2.0.0)
    sdoc (0.3.20)
      json (>= 1.1.3)
      rdoc (~> 3.10)
    selenium-webdriver (2.35.1)
      childprocess (>= 0.2.5)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
      rubyzip (< 1.0.0)
      websocket (~> 1.0.4)
    shoulda-matchers (2.4.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
    sprockets (2.10.0)
      hike (~> 1.2)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
      rack (~> 1.0)
      tilt (~> 1.1, != 1.3.0)
    sprockets-rails (2.0.0)
      actionpack (>= 3.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0)
      sprockets (~> 2.8)
    thor (0.18.1)
    thread_safe (0.1.3)
      atomic
    tilt (1.4.1)
    treetop (1.4.15)
      polyglot
      polyglot (>= 0.3.1)
    turbolinks (1.3.0)
      coffee-rails
    tzinfo (0.3.37)
    uglifier (2.2.1)
      execjs (>= 0.3.0)
      multi_json (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
    warden (1.2.3)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    websocket (1.0.7)
    xpath (2.0.0)
      nokogiri (~> 1.3)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  activeadmin!
  bootstrap-sass
  capybara
  coffee-rails (~> 4.0.0)
  database_cleaner!
  devise
  factory_girl_rails
  growl
  haml-rails
  jbuilder (~> 1.2)
  jquery-rails
  kaminari
  launchy
  paperclip
  pg
  pg_search
  phony_rails
  rails (= 4.0.0)
  rails_12factor
  rb-fsevent (= 0.9.3)
  rspec-rails (~> 2.0)
  sass-rails (~> 4.0.0)
  sdoc
  selenium-webdriver (= 2.35.1)
  shoulda-matchers
  turbolinks
  uglifier (>= 1.3.0)
```

in my gemfile i have:
 `gem 'activeadmin', github: 'gregbell/active_admin', branch: 'rails4`'

I tried to delete gemfile.lock and rebundle everything but it's still not working.
Any ideas?

Comment: sovled, i changed in my gemfile:
gem 'activeadmin', github: 'gregbell/active_admin', branch: 'rails4', ref: '6c9e22ab09229b0903942179060c10cf5e3289d8' and it works :)

Comment: You should make the above an answer and accept it, this is the only thing that worked for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like the rails4 branch for active_admin was removed!

You can update your gemfile and specify a tag or commit reference. As of today v0.6.1 is the most up to date version, so you could do:

```
gem "activeadmin", github: "gregbell/active_admin", tag: "v0.6.1"
```

..and that would solve your problem. Alternatively, as you pointed out in your comment, choosing another specific revision would also get rid of the error.

```
gem "activeadmin", github: "gregbell/active_admin", ref: "82ff48d51525bdf55c96e50d8650d45f2a6716ed"
```